# ng-repeat over an associative array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to setup a nested repeat in angular using an associative array of arrays. For example I have a structure as such:

collections['key1'] = [obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4];

collections['key2'] = [obj5,obj6,obj7];

I want to have a view with a structure of:

```html
<div ng-repeat="collection in collections">
  <h4>{{collection.id}}</h4>
  <div ng-repeat="item in collection">
     <span>{{item.name | item.value}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

However as soon as I add in ng-repeat="collection in collections" my view becomes blank. Is there a way to do this in angular or will I need to update the way i'm storing my data if I want to loop it in such a way? Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if we see more of your code... Do you have some error messages?

Comment: Try `ng-repeat="(key,value) in collections"` and then iterate over the value object.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm just getting nothing on my page but the console is error free.

Comment: This is because when you are trying to print {{collection.id}} as collection is an array and does not have id as property so it failing. You are trying to print the index of the array. Check this plunkr where I am printing the name in items inside collections. https://plnkr.co/edit/UR6Fju?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you an example how to use it

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.school = {
      classes:[
        {name:"Class 1", peoples:["Peter","Sue","Marc"]},
        {name:"Class 2", peoples:["John","Edward","Sara"]}
      ]
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 
<div ng-repeat="class in school.classes">
  <h4>{{class.name}}</h4>
  <div ng-repeat="person in class.peoples">
    <label>{{person}}</label>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to accept this answer since it did clear things up. My error was that I had my outer collection declared as an array [] instead of an object {} so I couldn't ng-repeat (key,value) until I changed it.